# Theme hook MENU_CALLBACK not found

Tags: 7, routes

I am seeing this error in my logs:

```
Theme hook MENU_CALLBACK not found
```

What are the causes? I cannot find this exact phrase in google or d.o. This is an example menu item:

```
$items['user/%user/integration/%integration'] = array(
    'title' => 'View An Integration',
    'page callback' => 'integration_view_page',
    'page arguments' => array(3),
    'access callback' => 'is_owner',
    'access arguments' => array(1, 3),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

Yes, cleared caches, including menu cache. The actual page appears to load ok.

Comment: You should get a stack trace. Maybe the logs already provide that? If you look into the actual apache error.log file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was a mistake on my part. I recently performed a find and replace on my codebase to change all my menu hooks from MENU_LOCAL_TASKS to MENU_CALLBACK.

I clearly did this ignoring case, and also did not check properly as in my template.php, I now had...

```
$vars['secondary_local_tasks'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'MENU_CALLBACK',
    '#secondary' => $vars['tabs']['#secondary'],
);
```

instead of...

```
$vars['secondary_local_tasks'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'menu_local_tasks',
    '#secondary' => $vars['tabs']['#secondary'],
);
```

Because it was now called MENU_CALLBACK in caps, it confused me and I was looking in the wrong place. It is only when I went back and diff'd my entire backed up codebase did I notice it.

Lesson Learned: Find & Replace is not always a good idea :)